# Replace string of one stream with string in another stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, str-replace

Fun with streams... I have a `List<String>` of tokenized URLs, and a `List<UrlParametersConfig.UrlParameter>` of all the parameter values for those tokens. For example, my yaml file looks like:

```
urlParameterList:
  urlParameter:
  -
    parameter: propertyId
    value: c3329fc
 -
    parameter: cartId
    value: 123456
 ...
```

And the corresponding config class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="urlParameterList")
public class UrlParametersConfig {

    private List<UrlParameter> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();

    public UrlParametersConfig() {}

    public List<UrlParameter> getUrlParameter() { return this.urlParameters; }

    public static class UrlParameter {
        private String parameter;
        private String value;

        public String getParameter() {
            return parameter;
        }
        public void setParameter(String parameter) {
            this.parameter = parameter;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a list of URLs that contains something like
`www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/property/{propertyId}
www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/{propertyId}/{cartId}`

Everywhere `{propertyId}` is referenced I need to substitute `c3329fc`, and everywhere `{cartId}` is referenced I need to substitute `123456a`. I figured out I'd be working with two streams, but I don't know which to stream first, the list of all URLs or the list of config parameters. Can anyone show me what this token replacement code should look like? So far this is what I have:

```
List<String> parameterizeUrls = uris.stream()
        .forEach(it -> {
            if (it.contains(parameters.stream()
                  .map(UrlParametersConfig.UrlParameter::getParameter)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList()))
   // do something?
        });
```

Comment: Imagine you are using Spring there could be something like `PropertyPlaceholderconfigurer` of interest for you... Just saying.

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correclty the idea, we want to obtain the following:

```
www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/property/c3329fc
www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/c3329fc/123456
```

One stream is necessary to loop on the list of original `url`s with tokens. For each `url`, another stream will loop on the list of parameters, executing reduction of the `url` for each parameter.

To be more clear and to avoid too much nesting, the algo is split in the following parts:

1) Main loop, transforming the original list of urls with tokens into urls with replaced values:

```
List<String> urlsTokenReplaced = urls.stream().map(url ->
  replaceTokens(url, params)
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2) For the specified `url`, replaces the occurrences of each token from the list.

```
private static String replaceTokens(String url, List<UrlParametersConfig.UrlParameter> params) {
  return params.stream()
               .reduce(url, {ClassName}::replaceToken, (prev, cur) -> cur);
}
```

*Update*

Details on how the reduction operation works: [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html).

For this particular case:

- `url` param is the starting value of the loop, for example `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/{propertyId}/{cartId}`.
- `{ClassName}::replaceToken` references the static method below, it is the so-called *accumulator* function, which takes the previous (or starting) value and produces a new value by applying the current `UrlParameter` on it. In our case, on the first pass it will produce `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/c3329fc/{cartId}` and `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/c3329fc/123456` on the second.
- `(prev, cur) -> cur)` is the so-called *collector* function. It defines what to do with the `prev`ious and the `cur`rent (produced by the accumulator) values. Here we just forget about the previous value and return the current, which will be reused by the accumulator on next iteration of the loop and so on. In our case, on the first pass it will return the second value between `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/{propertyId}/{cartId}` and `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/c3329fc/{cartId}`. On the second pass, it will return the second value from `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/c3329fc/{cartId}` and `www.comany.com/v2/rest/v2/sale/c3329fc/123456`.

When all the `UrlParameter`s from the stream are passed through, the last value produced by the accumulator (and thus the collector here) is returned from the method. If the stream were empty, the starting value (first arg) would be returned.

*enf-of-update*

3) Replaces a single occurrence of the specified token in the `url`:

```
private static String replaceToken(String url, UrlParametersConfig.UrlParameter param) {
  String replaceRegex = "\\{" + param.getParameter() + "\\}";
  return url.replaceAll(replaceRegex, param.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a lot of work. But I get a `PatternSyntaxException` on the `url.replaceAll()` line. It says `Illegal repetition near index 9
\{/brands/{id}\}`. The url parameter is `https://dev1.company.com/v2/trips/{id}/items/{itemId}/notifications`, and the param.parameters is `/brands/{id}`. I don't understand something, because we shouldn't be trying to make a replacement there at all...

Comment: This is because  the string `\{/brands/{id}\}` contains unescaped braces. There should be a backslash before each inner brace. `replaceRegex` should be adjusted to take such cases into account.
Generally, `/brands/{id}` should not be used as a token/parameter name. This should be only `id`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the URLs have the brackets in the WADL. But I stripped them off before calling `replaceTokens`, and it works! Would you mind explaining the me what the `reduce` method is doing? I have yet to fully understand that...

Comment: I updated the answer we an explanation of how `reduce` works in this case. Hope that helps.